# Animation doubles duration every time it appears in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to coding and I am working on a little game with pygame. I have a Sprite for an explosion animation, the first times it appears it works great for the whole game, but once you are playing a second or third game the explosions lasts more every time even though I empty the sprite group every time the game restarts, I think the problem might be that the explosion update function doesn't works well for more than one game, but I don't really know how to fix it. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    expl_img = []
    def __init__(self, center):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = self.cargaImagenes()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 50
        
    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                
        if now -self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame +=1
            if self.frame == len(self.expl_img):
                self.kill()
                
            else:
                center = self.rect.center
                self.image = self.expl_img[self.frame] 
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center
    
    
    def cargaImagenes(self):
        for i in range(9):
            filename = 'regularExplosion0{}.png'.format(i)
            img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
            img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
            img_def = pygame.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
            self.expl_img.append(img_def)
        return self.expl_img[0]
```

Here is where the explosion appears:

```
            if self.player.estado == self.player.Estado.volando:
                anticolision = False
                colisiones = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.asteroides, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
                
                for colision in colisiones:
                    
                    start_ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()                  
                    if colision and not anticolision:
                        anticolision = True 
                        print("anticolision true")                        
                        expl = Explosion(colision.rect.center)
                        self.explosionSound.play()
                        self.all_sprites.add(expl)                  
                        self.vidas -= 1
                        segundos = (pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000
                        if segundos > 3:
                            anticolision = False
                            print("anticolision false")
                    elif colision and anticolision:
                        pass

                    if self.vidas == 0:     
                        self.gameOver()
                        running= False
```

Comment: How do you start the explosion? Do you create a new instance of `Explosion`? If not you have to set `self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()` when the explosion is started.

Comment: I create a new instance of explosion every time a collision is made, I'll edit the question to show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.cargaImagenes()` is called every time when you create a new instance of `Explosion`. Therefore the number of elements in the class variable `expl_img` grows continuously. Only add new items to the list when the list is empty:

```py
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    expl_img = []

    # [...]

    def cargaImagenes(self):
  
        if not expl_img:                   # <---
            for i in range(9):
                filename = 'regularExplosion0{}.png'.format(i)
                img = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, filename)).convert()
                img.set_colorkey(BLACK)
                img_def = pygame.transform.scale(img, (75, 75))
                self.expl_img.append(img_def)

        return self.expl_img[0]
```